# Django child template not including content in template tags from base.html

Tags: html, django, inheritance

I have a problem in inheriting template from *base.html* for my about page (*about.html*). Meanwhile, I am able to extend *base.html* to *home.html*. I suspect it is an issue of syntax somewhere either in *base.html* or *about.html*, but could not possibly find it. It might also be *base.html* is only inherited by *home.html*. Can you please help? 
My *base. html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> {% block title %}{% endblock %} </title>
    <h1> {% block h1 %}{% endblock %} </h1>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block two %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My *about.html*:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %} 
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    {% block title %}About{% endblock %}
    {% block h1 %}Hi,About!{% endblock %}

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Part of my *views.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from ecomstore.catalog.models import Category, Product
from django.template import RequestContext


def about(request, template_name="about.html"):
    page_title='About'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),RequestContext(request))
```

My *urls.py*:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views as catalog_views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'$',catalog_views.home,name='home'),
url(r'^about/$',catalog_views.about,name='about'),
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is happening, and how is that different from what you expect? Also, show your view; and note that in a child template nothing that's outside of a block can ever be rendered.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman The problem is the template tag for  'about.html' has the same h1 tag as home.html, while it should display "Hi, About!" as per the tag in 'about.html'. I have checked my views and urls ; they route to 127.0.0.1:8000/about.

Answer (score 1):

In your `about.html` template you need to add

```
{% block content %}
    <!-- Add your about content here -->
{% endblock content %}
```

You also don't need `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags in the about.html file as they are in the base.html file already

Answer (score 0):

I think you want you about.html to look like this.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %} 
{% block title %}About{% endblock %}
{% block content %}Hi,About!{% endblock %}
```

Note: You have an `<h1>` in your header and I think you actually want that in your `<body>`

Comment: I tried the suggested solutions , but the url (127.0.0.1:8000/about/) only shows the home.html while it should display about.html. I have checked my views.py and urls.py files.

Comment: That's because you don't have anything in your about.html.  You're loading it into your header

Comment: I copy+ paste the code into 'about.html', but still the template displayed in the template tags is from 'home.html'. I have read (in a Django Book) that we can only extend base.html to only one template. I have also tried to extend 'home.html' but this did not work either.

Comment: `{% extends 'base.html' %}` must be the very first line of the about.html file.  Try moving Hi, About as I've edited it.  This works for everyone else so will work for you

Answer (score 0):

When you extend base.html your base.html defines entire html page. In your about.html you just need to code what you want to insert in  base.html blocks. So, your about.html have to like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %} 
{% block title %}
   About
{% endblock %}
{% block h1 %}
   Hi,About!
{% endblock %}
```